# How do I Force suspension of Metro app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How do we force an app to Suspend (NOT shutdown, just suspend) and then force-resume it ourselves when we are NOT using visual studio/debugging?

Comment: what is your motivation?

Comment: I am having mixed results. When I test my app while debugging and Suspend and Resume my app; all data and state is saved and loaded - as expected. When I publish my app and use it on my PC without debugging, I lose everything when it suspends.

Comment: So I was thinking, if only I could force it to suspend and resume at will, just so I didn't have to wait too long just to test something, probably many times.

Comment: In VS try Suspensed and Restart instead of just Suspend. I guess that is tha state that makes you trouble

Comment: I just went to help the OP. Until I realised that I was the one who wrote this question. :-/

Answer (score 2):

When running under Visual Studio 2012, you can enable the Debug Location on the debugger toolbar. This will allow you to select one of the three operations, "suspend", "resume", and "suspend and shutdown".

[edited]
Sorry, just noticed that you are asking for non VS solution. You can suspend your app by dragging the app down. Move your cursor to the top of the page until you see a hand. Click and hold it and pull down to suspend your app. It takes a few seconds before the app actually enter suspend mode. If you want to do things sooner, you can use visibility change to toggle certain action first, like saving critical stuff.